# Remove index.php from google search URL

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I want to be able to remove [index.php URL](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xcs79ygtfktmgu8/Screenshot%202015-05-16%2018.49.59.png?dl=0) from google's search listing, you may be able to see this when searching the website title (with or without a space between). On the second page for me it shows my website however the URL has index.php on the end!

**I have edited the httpd.conf** to remove index.php from the end of my URL, below you can see what I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName joemethven.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/joemethven/
</VirtualHost>

Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Why is Google picking up index.php when the website loads with joemethven.com? Is there a way I can prevent this?!

Thanks for reading, hope someone can help! :)

**Update:** I just quickly added a .htaccess within the folder of my website with the below information:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

I don't know if this will make any changes, however my other servers running websites without this issue had this information in their .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

The fix was easier than I thought, simply going to Google's webmaster tools I used the "Submit to Index" function and set my preferred URL without index.php and it's changed over for me!